# When i click Button to change textview in ListView , changed last row or another row textview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

i have costum ListView like this :

Row1   `Button1(-)    TextView      Button2(+)`

Row2   `Button1(-)    TextView      Button2(+)`

Row3   `Button1(-)    TextView      Button2(+)`

Row4   `Button1(-)    TextView      Button2(+)`

Row5   `Button1(-)    TextView      Button2(+)`

when i try `setOnClickListener` in getView for any `Button` , changed another Row `TextView` .

i Click Row 2 / `Button2(+)` , so `TextView` Must `++` (1 to 2) or Click Row 2 / `Button1(-)` , `TextView` Must `--` ( 2 to 1) But `TextView` in Row 5 changed to `--` or `++` .

This is My Adapter

```
public class adap_Mive extends BaseAdapter {

Context contextt;

private LayoutInflater myInflater;
public List<dm_Mive> list;

public adap_Mive(Context context) {
    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    contextt = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public void setData(List<dm_Mive> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public void clearData() {
    // clear the data
    list.clear();
}

Holder holder = null;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView                         = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_custom_froot, parent, false);
        holder                                 = new Holder();
        holder.tv_lbl_name                  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title)  ;
        holder.tv_lbl_details               = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_weight  );
        holder.tv_lbl_price                 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price)  ;
        holder.txt                          = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_meghda  r);
        holder.tv_img_pic                   = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.btn2                          = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_kam  );
        holder.btn1                            = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_zia  d);
        holder.btn_more                     = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mor  e);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_lbl_name.setText                  ((list.get(position).getname()));
    holder.tv_lbl_details.setText               ((list.get(position).getdetails()));
    holder.tv_lbl_price.setText                 ((list.get(position).getprice()));

    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.txt.setText("10");
        }
    });

    holder.btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.txt.setText("9");
        }
    });

    String profpic = list.get(position).getbmp();

    String Image_Name = null;

    String pic[] = profpic.split("/");
    for (String item : pic) {
        Image_Name = item;
    }

    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File picDir  = new File(extStore, "Froot");
    File file = new File(picDir, Image_Name);

    String ProfPic = file.toString();

    File f = new File(file.toString());
    if(f.exists())
    {
        holder.tv_img_pic.setImageURI              (Uri.parse(ProfPic));
    }
    else
    {
        Picasso.with(contextt)
                .load(profpic)
                .into(holder.tv_img_pic);
        Mod_Dwonload_File mdf = new Mod_Dwonload_File();
        mdf.Download_Adapter_Files(profpic);
    }

    return convertView;
}

public static class Holder
{
    public boolean needInflate;
    TextView    tv_lbl_name;
    TextView    tv_lbl_details;
    TextView    tv_lbl_price;
    ImageView   tv_img_pic;
    TextView    txt;
    ImageButton btn1;
    ImageButton btn2;
    ImageButton btn_more;
}

}
```

Comment: holder.txt.setText("10");

What is the statement you gave in this line?

Answer (score 0):

```
 final Holder  holder                                 = new Holder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView                         = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_custom_froot, parent, false);

        holder.tv_lbl_name                  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title)  ;
        holder.tv_lbl_details               = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_weight  );
        holder.tv_lbl_price                 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price)  ;
        holder.txt                          = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_meghda  r);
        holder.tv_img_pic                   = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.btn2                          = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_kam  );
        holder.btn1                            = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_zia  d);
        holder.btn_more                     = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mor  e);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_lbl_name.setText                  ((list.get(position).getname()));
    holder.tv_lbl_details.setText               ((list.get(position).getdetails()));
    holder.tv_lbl_price.setText                 ((list.get(position).getprice()));
    holder.txt  ((list.get(position).gettextvalue)); //create the textvalue string in dm_Mive class nd set value empty

    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          int butttonpostion = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
       //  String v1=   holder.txt  .gettext();
        String v1=list.get(butttonpostion).gettextvalue);// direct get value to list

        dm_Mive dm= new dm_Mive()
        dm_Mive.settextvalue(v1);
       dm_Mive.setname(list.get(buttonpostion).getname())
        ..
        ....
      friendlist.set(butttonpostion, dm);

        }
    });
```

Comment: if he is having 1000 button then do he write setOnClickListner 1000 times ??

Comment: Nops only one time you used the setonclicklister in adapter.

Comment: Solved , i must used getParent not getTag || View pv = (View) view.getParent(); TextView txt = (TextView)pv.findViewById(R.id.txt_meghdar);txt.setText("10");

Comment: now i have another problem , i can get TextView.getText , but can't get another TextView.getText , is null , why ?

Comment: holder.txt.getText();

Comment: in holder.btn2.setOnClickListener i want getText , i have two textView : TextView txt1 = (TextView) pv.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                TextView txt2 = (TextView) pv.findViewById(R.id.txt2); , i can getText From txt1 , but txt2 is null , why ??? (pv is my view : View pv = (View) view.getParent(); )

Comment: Holder holder1 = (Holder) v.getTag();
            holder1.txt.setText("10"); is not work for me , is null too

Comment: ok fine if you want text only use this <holder.text.getText().toString()> and final the holder object final Viewholder  holder = new Viewholder();
but list scroll up down is changed.                                              
the best way you can get value and store in List<dm_Mive> list.                 

 onClick method
 dm_Mive dm= new dm_Mive();
  dm... set get text values in dm_mive
 list.add(dm); you need more explanation i m here dudde.

Comment: Tank You Dear , Solved my Problem , in that code , list.get(position).get....() is best way , getText was not good ;)